# Getting NotSerializableException for org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair

Tags: android, exception, serialization, queue

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair
```

I have a class named `RequestData` which contains a

> List<NameValuePair>.

while setting data into that list i do

> paramList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("abc","xyz"));

now I have a

> private static Queue <RequestData> requestDataQueue = new
>   LinkedBlockingQueue<RequestData>();

which stores multiple RequestData objects in sequence in another class.

This is how my RequestData class looks.

```
/**
 * The Requests sent for the server are of this class` format.
 * */
public class RequestData implements Serializable
{
    static final long serialVersionUID = 89698204;

    private UUID uuid;
    private String url;
    private List<NameValuePair> paramList;

... // getter setters follows
}
```

but when i go to serialize or deserialize it gives the exception.

```
08-16 17:29:24.595: W/System.err(9684): java.io.WriteAbortedException: Read an exception; java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair
08-16 17:29:24.595: W/System.err(9684):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:804)
08-16 17:29:24.595: W/System.err(9684):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
08-16 17:29:24.595: W/System.err(9684):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1960)
08-16 17:29:24.595: W/System.err(9684):     at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:657)
08-16 17:29:24.595: W/System.err(9684):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-16 17:29:24.595: W/System.err(9684):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-16 17:29:24.603: W/System.err(9684):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1354)
08-16 17:29:24.603: W/System.err(9684):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1266)
08-16 17:29:24.603: W/System.err(9684):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1855)
08-16 17:29:24.603: W/System.err(9684):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
08-16 17:29:24.603: W/System.err(9684):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
08-16 17:29:24.603: W/System.err(9684):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1960)
08-16 17:29:24.603: W/System.err(9684):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1137)
08-16 17:29:24.603: W/System.err(9684):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
08-16 17:29:24.603: W/System.err(9684):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1369)
08-16 17:29:24.603: W/System.err(9684):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1266)
08-16 17:29:24.603: W/System.err(9684):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1855)
08-16 17:29:24.603: W/System.err(9684):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
08-16 17:29:24.603: W/System.err(9684):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
08-16 17:29:24.603: W/System.err(9684):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1960)
08-16 17:29:24.603: W/System.err(9684):     at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.readObject(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:875)
08-16 17:29:24.603: W/System.err(9684):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-16 17:29:24.603: W/System.err(9684):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-16 17:29:24.603: W/System.err(9684):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1354)
08-16 17:29:24.611: W/System.err(9684):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1266)
08-16 17:29:24.611: W/System.err(9684):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1855)
08-16 17:29:24.611: W/System.err(9684):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
08-16 17:29:24.611: W/System.err(9684):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
08-16 17:29:24.611: W/System.err(9684):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1960)
08-16 17:29:24.611: W/System.err(9684):     at com.expersis.newpm.data.OfflineDataStore.deserializeData(OfflineDataStore.java:35)
```

I also see the exception pointing to LinkedBlockingQueue but that should not be any problem.
Also I'm using

> org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair 
>   which implements Serializable.

don't know whats the problem

Please guide...

Comment: Is your `NameValuePair` (not `BasicNameValuePair`) class implements Serializable? Can you show code of this class please?

Comment: NameValuePair is an Interface from android.
BasicNameValuePair implements NameValuePair

Comment: Ok:) In Android java BasicNameValuePair is not implements Serializable: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair.html